# wordpress mobile theme infected

Tags: wordpress, security, hyperlink, code-injection, malware

I was informed by google that my wordpress website has been hacked. i installed wordfence and i scanned al my files, I deleted all the infected plugins and restored all my original files. I scanned again, all is clean, i sent the reports (many scanners) to google, they verified and remove the "this site may be hacked" message.

I tried now to open my website to check the responsive mobile design on my samsung note 5, before the theme appearing about 300 little hyperlink such arx arm bmp amzd , every hyper link takes me to a scam website. My website is injected for sure how can i clean it from those hyperlinks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that your database is clean from all those infected links, it surely happened due to some vulnerable plugin or a theme, before you perform any action, backup your entire site, ground it, scan it using some reasonable wordpress virus detectors. Once you're done with it, start scanning your database for any unusual pages and links that you might have seen on your website. After performing this cleanup process. Install a fresh copy of wordpress by downloading it from the official website and install latest version of each and every plugin, also make sure to google about those plugins whether they are safer to use or not. import your wp_posts table at last and try to avoid importing unnecessary or easy to post / add stuffs.

Answer (score 1):

Backup the database via PHPMyAdmin and completely uninstall WP. Then reinstall it again and restore the database.

Also, update any passwords on your webserver and even do a fresh install of the webserver.

Finally, avoid installing plugin's that aren't from the official repo as these can cause infections to your site.

Comment: backup the database ===> remove wordpress ==> re install it ? I don't want to repeat all the design, widgets and plugins.. :/

Comment: @ElioChamy you may have to. If it's severely infected there's not much you can do about it. Most of the info is stored in the DB so it should restore when you put the DB back.